# How to Delete the Residual Files of Uninstalled Apps in Android Phones?

Tags: android, mobile

How to delete the residual files of apps which we have uninstalled from the Android phones? Can we manually delete them? Is there an app for this task? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the private app files should have been deleted when the app was uninstalled. Anything leftover would live in public storage, like the sdcard (which may or may not refer to an actual physical sdcard). Presumably any app that can access these files, like a file browser, picture gallery, etc., can delete them. You can look for such apps on Google Play.